# Click on part of text in a span tag watir

Tags: text, message, watir

I have this html code:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class=message>
      <div class=div10l>Fill In All Fields With<IMG style="CURSOR: hand" border=0 alt="Not  Null" src="../img/re.gif">.</div>
      <span style="COLOR: red">
        <a href="../main/Error.jsp" target=_blank>
          <span style="COLOR: red">Exception: ERROR: duplicate key value</span>
        </a>
        <br>
      </span>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

If there is error on the page I get the message Exception: ERROR: duplicate key value, which is the link for a detailed explanation. How can I click on this text using only part of text - Exception?

I tried ie1.span(:text => /Exception: ERROR:/).click, but the link isn't opened.

If I try ie1.link(:href, "../main/Error.jsp").click - I get the following:

```
can't find the object - 
E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:66:in `assert_exists': Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["a"], :href=>"../main/Error.jsp"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
    from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:414:in `perform_action'
    from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:269:in `click!'
    from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:211:in `click'
    from file1.rb:53:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser.link(:text => /Exception: ERROR:/).click
```

This is clicking the link based on its text. The text of the span within the anchor tag counts as the anchor tags text.